# Convolution (Literally)

Tags: mathematics, word, enigmatic-puzzle

Decode the following message.

[image]

Hint:

> Refer to the title.

Additional hint:

> Kernel is $\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}$.

> The answer is Sny confirmed, but can you get a clearer image by reversing the convolution (instead of applying an approximate inverse convolution)?

Comment: Just a wild guess, but is the answer "Sny"? :-)

Comment: :-) IHATE15CHAR

Comment: It's always Sny. XD

Comment: Now the question is how :)

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: Not my downvote, but perhaps the concept "101 grid/cell-style puzzles whose answer is usually 'Sny'" could use some refinement, especially since most of them seem to be write-ins. There may have been a nice aha effect to your first puzzles, but it has worn thin by now, at least for me. Sorry to be so negative. Your puzzles seem to have their fans and I don't mind that you post them, but I don't really care for them, either.

Comment: The purpose of the puzzle is not the answer but the process. Negative comments are fine, no problem.

Answer (score 1):

All my time spent watching 3B1B on YouTube has led to this moment (he has a video covering convolutions).

Coding the image into a matrix of color-corresponding values of 0, 1, 2, and 3 (where darker ~ larger number), we can get a matrix like the following:

```
1 2 2 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
2 3 2 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
2 3 2 1 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 1 1
1 2 3 2 2 2 3 3 2 2 2 2 2
1 2 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 2
1 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 3 2
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 3 2
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 2 1
```

Then, assuming a sharpening kernel of:

```
 0 -1  0
-1  4 -1
 0 -1  0
```

I get an output (assuming the edges are 0 and extending the edges) of:

```
 0  -1  -2  -2  -1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
-1   0   2   3   1  -1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
-2   2   3   0   0  -2  -1  -2  -2  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1   0
-2   2   3  -1  -2   0  -1   2   2  -1   0   0   0   1  -1
-1  -1  -1   3   0   1   0   3   3   0   1   0   0   3  -2
-1   0   0   3   0   1   1   0   0   1   0   3   2   1  -2
-1   1   3   2  -1   0   0   0   0   0  -2  -1   2   1  -2
 0  -1  -2  -2  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -2   0   0   3   2  -2
 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  -1   1   3   2   0  -1
 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  -1  -2  -2  -1   0
```

Which, conveniently re-colored in Excel using conditional formatting, looks like:

[image]

And finally (somewhat) reads like "S n y"! (As the comments correctly guessed)

Comment: Upvoted, but consider that my image is likely not the input of the convolution but the output of the convolution. The kernel is $\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: I'm a 3b1b fan too :-)

Comment: @JaapScherphuis the problem is that we're trying to reverse the convolution, not apply a convolution.

Comment: @SnySmartie Yes, and he one Alexander is applying here is the (first order approximate) inverse of yours.

Comment: Surely a better inverse can be used, since you can't really tell.
Can you link me to a resource about inverses of convolutions? @JaapScherphuis thanks.

Comment: @SnySmartie Most resources about [deconvolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deconvolution) go straight to FFT which allow the inverse to be calculated properly by a simple division on the transformed array. Anyway, Alexander's inverse is only a first order approximation, but you could do a 5x5 second order approximation, etc. I agree that it is not a great solution in this case since it is much easier to solve exactly using the light-chasing method used in lights-out games.

Comment: ^ The light-chasing method was what I was aiming for. I'm a fan of FFT :-)